# Access 2013 Complicated SUM on Query/Report

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a query in Access 2013 that shows the current status and date, while ignoring older status records.

I have three tables:

```
customer 
-id (pk) 
-last 
-first

status 
-id (pk) 
status 
description

status-customer 
id (pk) 
customer_id 
status_id 
status_date 
notes
```

I would like to create  list of customers with a sum of how many days they are at a certain status.

Consider the following joined table:

```
Last        First        Customer_id         Status_date       Status
John         Smith              1               05/1/2015        A
John         Smith              1               05/10/2015       B
John         Smith              1               05/14/2015       A
John         Smith              1               05/30/2015       B 
Mary         Johnson            2               05/26/2015       A
```

I want something that looks like this:

```
                                                                Days in
 Last        First        Customer_id         Status_date       Status A
 John         Smith              1               05/1/2015        25     
 Mary         Johnson            2               05/26/2015       5
```

Note that the days counted are only those between A & B. So for John Smith, the interval between record one and two is added to the interval between record three and four.  If the status does not change from A to B, then the current date is used to figure out the total.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correlated sub-select, derived table, group by etc. I don't know how MS Access subtracts dates, so `SUM(statusB - statusA)` may need to be adjusted.

```
select Last,
       First,
       Customer_id,
       MIN(statusdateA),
       SUM(statusdateB - statusdateA)
(
select Last,
       First,
       Customer_id,
       Status_date as statusdateA,
       (select min(t2.Status_date) from tablename t2
        where t2.Status_date > t1.Status_date
          and t2.status = 'B') as statusdateB
from tablename t1
where status = 'A'
) dt
group by Last, First, Customer_id
```